# C# "Method not defined" when adding a new method to a mocked interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface

I am currently writing unit tests that uses methods from one of my mocked interfaces. Everything works fine, but when I add a new method to the interface (the connection between the interface and its base class is fine), the mocked interface in my unit test project does not pick up the new method, throwing a "method not defined" error. Here is a basic example of how I am adding new methods.

Base Class:

```
namespace MyProject.Business
{
    public class MyProjectValidator: IValidator
    {
        private readonly IValidator mValidator;

        public MyProject(IValidator validator)
        {
            this.mValidator= validator;
        }

        public bool myMethod()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool myNewMethod()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
namespace MyProject.Business
{
    public interface IValidator
    {
       bool myMethod();
       bool myNewMethod ();
    }
}
```

Unit Tests (different project, same solution)

```
using MyProject.Business;
namespace MyProject.Tests.Business
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyProjectTests
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void testMethods()
        {
             var testValidator= new Mock<IValidator>();
             var testMyProject= new MyProject(testValidator.Object);

             var testOld = testValidator.myMethod(); // testOld = true
             var testNew = testValidator.myNewMethod(); // error: myNewMethod() not defined
         }
     }
}
```

As I commented above, my newly added method is not being recognized. My old method was created before the unit test project was created (I assume, I am inheriting code from a former developer). I tried checking the references in the unit test project for a failed linkage but all of the functions of IValidator appear. I have tried rebuilding and restarting & rebuilding both the solution and the project to no avail.

Any guidance concerning why "myNewMethod()" is not being recognized in my unit test project would be appreciated.

Update: added the using line as requested.

Comment: namespace......put  `using MyProject.Business`

Comment: I apologize, I have that in my projects and I don't believe this is the issue. I will update the example.

Comment: `public void testMethonds` is that a typo

Comment: It is. I corrected it but that shouldn't effect the issue at hand

Comment: How does `testValidator.myMethod()` even compile? `testValidator` is an instance of `Mock<IValidator>`, so it doesn't have that method (but `testValidator.Object` does).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'll add the appropriate context. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: just a note. we dont know what you really have in your project. so when you put your code here put it correctly.

Comment: `public void testMethods` is a method, right? Shouldn't there be `()`? Have you actually executed this code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I'm working on a proprietary system right now so I can't be as detailed as I want to

Comment: @31eee384 thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You don't have to post your original code, necessarily, but you should try to make a set of code that actually exhibits the bug you want people to see when run.

Comment: Is it possible there's an extension method for `Mock<IValidator>` (say `static bool myMethod(this Mock<IValidator> m)` that does `return m.Object.myMethod();`? This would explain why it doesn't require `.Object.`.

Comment: I'm not sure. I am using Ninject as a plugin for this project which allows me to bind the interface to references of the class as such:
   `kernel.Bind<IValidator>().To<MyProjectValidator>();`

Comment: That's raises a good point, you should probably add tags/descriptions of the tech you're using. I'm not actually sure what that line you posted does, since I've never used Ninject. Does that answer the earlier question from @MarkSeemann "How does `testValidator.myMethod()` even compile?" If not I still don't see a clear answer to that. (Extension methods are a long shot: I doubt anyone would make the effort to do that instead of just doing `.Object`. You should be able to tell for sure by F12ing or using the "Quick Info" tool though.)

Comment: @32eee384 I looked into it further and you hit the nail on the head. The new method I just added was missing the object reference that was defined elsewhere for the original. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of a comment by @31eee384, the problem was indeed related to the lack of an object reference. Changing the call to `testValidator.Object.myNewMethod();` (the object reference to the interface for the original method had been hidden elsewhere) allowed the method to be recognized. Thank you all for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The problem also here is that you are invoking the methods of a Mock. The only things you should be doing with that testValidator is setting your expectations and call results and do some verifications (if any). You should never be calling an interface method from a mock because it really doesn't make sense; you want to test your business class and will use the mock to help you with any relevant behaviour the interface provides your business class. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.